# Cannot deserialize JSON with missing polymorphic field

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I have class as follows

```
class XYZ {
    private String type;

    private TypeSpecific typeSpecific;

    public TypeSpecific getTypeSpecific() {
        return typeSpecific;
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, 
        property = "type"           
        )
    @JsonSubTypes({     
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ATypeSpecific.class, name = "a")
    })
    public void setTypeSpecific(TypeSpecific typeSpecific) {
       this.typeSpecific = typeSpecific;
    }
}
```

Class ATypeSpecific extends TypeSpecific.

I want to deserialize JSON
`{"type":"b"}`
where typeSpecific will be set as null in object. But I am getting following exception:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Missing property 'typeSpecific' for external type id 'type'`

How do I deserialize above mentioned JSON into the object?

Dependency versions:

jackson-annotations: 2.7.0,
jackson-core: 2.7.4,
jackson-databind: 2.7.4

I have tried with latest patch, i.e. 2.7.9 and latest version 2.8.6. But it is not working.
Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to mark the field as optional

Answer (score 1):

In my case, having:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, property = "@c")
class CommonReq{};

class AReq extend CommonReq{};
```

In spring mvc, use `@RequestBody AReq` to receive json http body, i got this error like `missing subtype`,

and I add `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)` annotation for `AReq`, finally fixed this problem.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set following property to make it run:

```
// for version 1.x       
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
// for newer versions
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

Comment: you have set `property = "type"` in  `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation property. that is causing conflict between String parameter `type` and `typeSpecific`. Rename property to some other name, then my solution will work

Comment: I renamed `type` to `format` and changed corresponding getters/setters. Still it is not working. Am I missing something here? How does naming cause conflict?

Comment: I am asking you to rename 
`@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, 
        property = "type"           
        )`
to
`@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, 
        property = "format"           
        )`

Comment: Yes I renamed that as well along with my JSON. Now my JSON is `{"format":"b"}`. The solution should also work for JSON `{"format":"a","typeSpecific":{//fields}}`. Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@JsonProperty
private Optional<TypeSpecific> typeSpecific;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
        property = "type",
        defaultImpl = NoClass.class)
```